# how to customize border of Icon TextBox Form in Native-Base?

Tags: react-native, native-base

i use Native-Base in my react project. and i want to customize width of border Icon TextBox form in Native-Base. 
this my code

```
<Item>
   <Icon active name='lock' />
   <Input placeholder='password'/>
</Item>
```

this is the show

[image]

so, how to customize the margin right in the border?. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Item>
   <Icon active name='lock' style={{borderWidth: 10}}/>
   <Input placeholder='password'/>
</Item>
```